# How to remove Hook 1 (expr -- @import UIKit display @import Appkit) in Xcode console

Tags: lldb, xcode9.4

My used command `echo display @import UIKit >> ~/.lldbinitecho display @import AppKit >> ~/.lldbinit` at mac terminal app to load UIKit in order to print frame or bounds to Xcode console, but when used that command later, Xcode console always print :

```
- Hook 1 (expr -- @import UIKit display @import AppKit)

- Hook 2 (expr -- @import UIKit delete @import AppKit)

- Hook 3 (expr -- @import UIKit display @import AppKit)

error: Aborting reading of commands after command #0: 'expr -- @import UIKit 
display @import AppKit' failed with error: while importing modules:
error: Header search couldn't locate module AppKit

error: Aborting reading of commands after command #0: 'expr -- @import UIKit 
delete @import AppKit' failed with error: while importing modules:
error: Header search couldn't locate module AppKit

error: Aborting reading of commands after command #0: 'expr -- @import UIKit 
display @import AppKit' failed with error: while importing modules:
error: Header search couldn't locate module AppKit
```

I want to get rid of that but i don't know remove command, if someone know that please shared with me, thanks.

Comment: Please - don't post photos of errors. Insert it into your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
(lldb) undisplay <HOOK ID>
```

display is a slightly complex aliases for `target stop-hook add", it does:

```
(lldb) target stop-hook add -o "expr <YOUR TEXT>"
```

So you can also remove them using

```
(lldb) target stop-hook delete <HOOK ID>
```

And as you guessed, `undisplay` is an alias for the latter command.